# Lock-free job queue with arbitrary job arguments

Tags: c++, multithreading, cross-platform

Currently I'm using Microsoft's `Concurrency::concurrent_queue` class to distribute work across cores. The worker threads pull work from this queue. I have multiple job producers (but if really necessary, I can live with just one producer).

A job object is currently implemented like this:

```
struct Job
{
    void(*function_pointer)(void*); // Job function (used to execute the task)
    void* arguments;    // Job arguments (gets passed to the job function)
};
```

As you can see, this system requires that the job producer allocates memory for each job's arguments and keeps it allocated till the job is finished. That's exactly what I'm trying to get rid of, because it's annoying and error-prone. Of course I could replace the `void* arguments;` with something like `int argument;`. But my jobs have arbitrary numbers and types of arguments.

A simple solution would be to replace `void* arguments;` with something like this:

```
char* arguments;    // Points to byte buffer that contains the arguments.
```

and then allocate memory for each job's arguments by calling `new` (which gets deleted automatically when the job is finished). While this would work, an allocation per job would be bad for performance.
I thought about using a circular buffer (for storing the callbacks and arguments of all the jobs), but I couldn't find any implementation that can handle arbitrarily sized elements in a lock-free fashion.

**In short, I want to be able to do something like this:**

```
struct Job_arguments
{
    int argument1;
    char argument2;
    float argument3;
};
Job_arguments arguments(1, 2, 3.0f);
job_system->add_job(&callback, arguments); // Arguments get copied.
```

I hope the explanation of my problem was clear. If not, I can elaborate.

**EDIT:**
Sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm trying to get rid of the `Concurrency::concurrent_queue` to replace it with something that causes no allocations (like a circular buffer). The jobs should also be stored in a way that causes no allocations to occur.

Answer (score 4):

Have you met [`std::function<void()>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)?

It type erases any invokable object.  To bundle the arguments, just make a lambda `[=]{ some_function( some_arguments ); }` and pass it to `std::function<void()>`.

For efficiencies sake, move in, and only the one allocation is done.  Hopefully `try_pop` is written reasonably and the destination is moved into.

Use `[=]` to capture, as `[&]` capture is dangerous.  If you need a buffer, you can easily `[=]` copy the pointer in, then manually delete (dangerous and error prone), use C++14 style capture lists and owning buffers (`[buff=std::move(buff),=]`), or write your own custom object with its own `operator()`.

`[=]` can be mildly dangerous, because it silently captures everything mentioned, so you could list the variables you want to capture by value instead `[var1, var2, var2]`.

```
Concurrency::concurrent_queue< std::function< void() > > safe_queue;

// add to queue a call to `hello( some_string, some_int )`

void hello_to_queue( std::string some_string, int some_int ) {
  safe_queue.push( [=]{ hello(some_string, some_int); } );
}
```

this copies `some_string` and `some_int` into the lambda, moves the lambda into the `std::function<void()>`, then stores that `std::function<void()>` in the queue.

```
// dequeuer, runs elements until it cannot find any more:
void try_run() {
  std::function<void()> f;
  while(safe_queue.try_pop(f)) {
    f();
    f = nullptr;
  }
}
```

this repeatedly tries to extract `std::function<void()>`s from the queue.  Each time it succeeds, it runs the extracted function.  It then recycles the memory before trying to fill the `std::function` again, because why not do it early and not inside concurrent code.

Naturally a real use case involves signals etc.

A `std::function<?>` stores how to invoke the stored object, and any storage for the object.

A lambda can capture whatever values you want, and expose some code to be invoked.

Together they let you store "run this with no more arguments at some later time", store that in your concurrent queue, and run it in another thread.

`std::function` implementations can use SBO for small captured data cases to eliminate any allocation.  Move-expressions in lambda captures can prevent copying of any owned buffers (like `std::string` or `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr`).  In a decent quality implementation of std function, the captured data is stored along side the type erasure pimpl, so it will match your manual implementation's efficiency.  As it uses RAII to own the data, there is no risk of leaks.

Comment: Exactly the correct solution for the problem. But you should probably make a note about referencing stuff in the lambda being somewhat risky. Since the OP is worried about memory allocation, you may also want to note the use of SBO.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have any experience with lambdas. Also I have trouble understanding your answer. What do you mean with "For efficiencies sake, move in, and only the one allocation is done. Hopefully try_pop is written reasonably and the destination is moved into."? Also, are you talking about passing the arguments comfortably? Because I'm not worried about that. I'm worried about where they are stored.

Comment: @Dudeson more details added.  I would recommend reading up on `std::function` use and lambda use.

Comment: @Dudeson: If you don't have any lambda experience, then it's time to get some. As for where the arguments are stored, std::function will typically store them in the function object itself if they're small enough, else it will have to dynamically allocate.

Comment: @Puppy to be fair, my original answer was going to be "have you met `std::function<void()>`?" and leave it at that.  Elaboration beyond that may be useful, time will tell.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaboration and help! But I think the problem with this approach is, that there doesn't seem to be any guarantee that there will be no allocations. The jobs I'm creating are very fine grained (for example just a couple of matrix multiplications per job).

Comment: @Dudeson: You can make your own version of std::function with that guarantee if you need. But if your jobs are that small the overhead of even a lockless queue will be very high.

Comment: @Puppy: I might have exaggerated a bit.^^ I usually do like 100 particle update calls or other calculations in a single job (to relativize the scheduling overhead). "You can make your own version of std::function with that guarantee if you need" That's exactly my problem. I don't know how to store arbitrarily sized objects in a preallocated buffer, which must be accessible by multiple threads.